# Iterated algorithm for creating data matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, iteration

suppose that i want to create following data matrix

[image]

for creating such type of   matrix, i have already written code

```
function [ x ]=create_matrix1(b,l)
    n = length(b);
    m = n-l+1;
    x = zeros(m,l);
    for i=1:m
        x(i,:)=b(i:i+l-1);
    end;
end
```

but when  we have a large  data, then creating of such matrix  became  big problem, for instance  if we generate data  from matlab like this

```
load ampoutput2.mat
[m n]=size(y)

m =

      500000


n =

     1
```

if `p=2000` then of course  it will crush, computer will stop working, is there any iterated version which i can do for creating this matrix?thanks  very much

Comment: You have used `l,m,n, N, p` so interchangeably that you have got me confused. Given an `x` and `l` your task is to return `Xd` ? In the second piece of code you are loading a `500000 x 1` matrix which would be 4MB in MATLAB, insignificant for any modern computer. You already have an iterative version of the code, what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: but  can you imagine (500000-2000)  by 2000 matrix?

Comment: If your matrix doesn't fit in memory, then it doesn't matter what steps you use to try to build it, you won't be able to get it.  Are you sure you *need* to build the matrix?  Do you just need to multiply it against a vector or another matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the `hankel` function.  But you may not want to explicitly construct the matrix, depending on what you want to do with it.  You can multiply matrices of this type against vectors in O(N log N) time with some calls to `flip` and by using the FFT.

Answer (score 1):

the matrix can be efficiently created this way:

```
create_matrix2 = @(b, l) b(bsxfun(@plus, (1 : l), (0 : numel(b)-l)'));
```